# How do I get datatables to work with bootstrap4 tabs in Django templates?

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-4, datatables, django-templates

I have a Django template with multiple tables.  I am using Bootstrap 4 with datatables.  I wanted to put my tables in tabs, and that is giving me problems.  If the tables are not in tabs, this code works fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datatable').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Blfrtip',
          buttons: [
              'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
          ]
      } );
  } );
```

I looked at these two links: [Scrolling and Bootstrap tabs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html) and [Hidden initialisation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/flash/hidden). And got the snippet at the bottom of this post to work as datables (though the table widths have issues in Django).

However, that snippet only works with hard-coded tables.  In my Django template, I am using template tags to loop through query strings like this:

```
    {% if items %}
    <table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable" id="data">
        <th>Item Table</th>
         <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for item in items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.item.title|truncatechars:25 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
        <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
            No items
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

In Django using the snippet example, if I replace the first tab's hard coded table with that template for loop, the datatable only works for the first tab (i.e., no options, pagination, search...).  The same happens if I replace both the first and second tabs' hard coded tables with two different (but similar) for loops. If I replace the first and second tab's hard coded tables with the **same** template for loop, the tables work as datables in the first, second, and third tabs (though the table widths are wrong--full width only on the first tab).

I posted this question earlier, but at the time didn't realize the problem was just with the template tag for loops.  I can't put the Django template in the snippet, but I have this exact code working in a Django template with the hard coded tables and failing as described with the template loops.

Thanks for any thoughts or suggestions--

Al

I've moved the snippet down here for better readability:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datatable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
              buttons: [
                  'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
              ]
    });

    $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.pill', function (e) {
        $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
           .columns.adjust()
           .responsive.recalc();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

                       -<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- start -->
          <div class="card card-info card-tabs">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 pt-1 font-weight-bold" style="background: #98e48e">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="custom-tabs-tab" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link active" id="custom-tabs-tabone-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-tabone" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabone" aria-selected="true" style="color:black">First</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-tabtwo-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-tabtwo" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabtwo" aria-selected="false" style="color:black">Second</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-tabthree-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#custom-tabs-tabthree" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabthree" aria-selected="false" style="color:black">Third</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="custom-tabs-tabone" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabone-tab">
<table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-tabtwo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabtwo-tab">
<table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>George Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-tabthree" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabthree-tab">
<table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Beatrice Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
  </div><!-- /.content-wrapper end-->
Return to post
```

Comment: In your django template have you tried giving your tables unique ids? `<table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable" id="data_table_{{forloop.counter}}">`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your issue. I have replaced the `data-toggle="pill"` with `data-toggle="tab"` modified your javascript to destroy and reinitialize data tables once the tab has changed.

Please see below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Shared data table options.
  var dataTableOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
    ]
  };

  // Initialize on load.
  $('.datatable').DataTable(dataTableOptions);

  // Destroy and reinitialize table on tab change.
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var tabTarget = $(this).attr('href'); // #tab-id-value
    var $table = $(tabTarget).find('.datatable'); // Find data table.

    // If the data table has already been initialized, destroy it.
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable($table)) {
      $table.DataTable().destroy();
    }

    // Reinitialize with shared options.
    $table.DataTable(dataTableOptions);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.1.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.22/b-1.6.5/b-html5-1.6.5/b-print-1.6.5/r-2.2.6/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- start -->
  <div class="card card-info card-tabs">
    <div class="card-header p-0 pt-1 font-weight-bold" style="background: #98e48e">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="custom-tabs-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="custom-tabs-tabone-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#custom-tabs-tabone" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabone" aria-selected="true" style="color:black">First</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-tabtwo-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#custom-tabs-tabtwo" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabtwo" aria-selected="false" style="color:black">Second</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="custom-tabs-tabthree-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#custom-tabs-tabthree" role="tab" aria-controls="custom-tabs-tabthree" aria-selected="false" style="color:black">Third</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="custom-tabs-tabone" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabone-tab">
          <table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-tabtwo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabtwo-tab">
          <table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>George Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="custom-tabs-tabthree" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-tabthree-tab">
          <table class="table table-striped table-valign-middle datatable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Beatrice Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper end-->
```